# SQL CROSS Apply with comma delimited list

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to only show records that meet the location criteria. The dilemma is the locations are store in the comma delimited list which makes it harder.

Here is the code

```
DECLARE @sessionStart DATETIME, 
@sessionEnd DATETIME, 
@instructorKey INT, 
@locationKey INT 

SET @instructorKey = 1
SET @sessionStart = '2015-03-01'
SET @sessionEnd = '2015-04-05'
SET @locationKey = null 
SELECT SU.sessionUnitKey, s.locationKey,s.locationKeyList,SU.sessionStart, SU.sessionEnd
FROM sessionUnit SU WITH (NOLOCK) 
INNER JOIN session S WITH (NOLOCK) ON SU.sessionKey = S.sessionKey 
left JOIN location L WITH (NOLOCK) ON (S.locationKey = L.locationKey ) 
INNER JOIN product P WITH (NOLOCK) ON S.productKey = P.productKey 
INNER JOIN users U WITH (NOLOCK) ON SU.instructorKey = U.userKey 
INNER JOIN lkup_productType PT WITH (NOLOCK) ON P.productTypeKey = PT.productTypeKey 

CROSS APPLY DelimitedSplit8K('10,260,34,102,15', ',')  ds 
inner join Location L2 on L2.locationKey = ds.Item

WHERE 1=1 
AND EXISTS ( SELECT 1 from ins_car_loc ICL WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE ICL.RptingInskey = SU.instructorKey and ICL.instructorKey = @instructorKey and ICL.endDt is NULL ) 


AND (@sessionStart IS NULL OR SU.sessionStart >= @sessionStart) AND (@sessionEnd IS NULL OR SU.sessionStart <= @sessionEnd) 
ORDER BY SU.sessionUnitKey
```

and here is the sample output

```
sessionUnitKey  locationKey locationKeyList sessionStart    sessionEnd
171331  34  NULL    2015-03-04 07:15:00.000 2015-03-04 09:15:00.000
171331  34  NULL    2015-03-04 07:15:00.000 2015-03-04 09:15:00.000
171331  34  NULL    2015-03-04 07:15:00.000 2015-03-04 09:15:00.000
171331  34  NULL    2015-03-04 07:15:00.000 2015-03-04 09:15:00.000
171331  34  NULL    2015-03-04 07:15:00.000 2015-03-04 09:15:00.000
10:00:00.000
172374  NULL    15,10,34,102,260    2015-03-15 08:00:00.000 2015-03-15 10:00:00.000
172374  NULL    15,10,34,102,260    2015-03-15 08:00:00.000 2015-03-15 10:00:00.000
172375  NULL    4,5 2015-03-15 14:15:00.000 2015-03-15 16:15:00.000
172375  NULL    4,5 2015-03-15 14:15:00.000 2015-03-15 16:15:00.000
172375  NULL    4,5 2015-03-15 14:15:00.000 2015-03-15 16:15:00.000
172375  NULL    4,5 2015-03-15 14:15:00.000 2015-03-15 16:15:00.000
172375  NULL    4,5 2015-03-15 14:15:00.000 2015-03-15 16:15:00.000
172376  NULL    4,5 2015-03-15 16:30:00.000 2015-03-15 18:30:00.000
172376  NULL    4,5 2015-03-15 16:30:00.000 2015-03-15 18:30:00.000
172376  NULL    4,5 2015-03-15 16:30:00.000 2015-03-15 18:30:00.000
172376  NULL    4,5 2015-03-15 16:30:00.000 2015-03-15 18:30:00.000
172376  NULL    4,5 2015-03-15 16:30:00.000 2015-03-15 18:30:00.000
172377  NULL    4,5 2015-03-15 18:30:00.000 2015-03-15 20:30:00.000
172377  NULL    4,5 2015-03-15 18:30:00.000 2015-03-15 20:30:00.000
172377  NULL    4,5 2015-03-15 18:30:00.000 2015-03-15 20:30:00.000
172377  NULL    4,5 2015-03-15 18:30:00.000 2015-03-15 20:30:00.000
172377  NULL    4,5 2015-03-15 18:30:00.000 2015-03-15 20:30:00.000
172378  NULL    15,10,34,102,260    2015-03-09 06:00:00.000 2015-03-09 08:00:00.000
172378  NULL    15,10,34,102,260    2015-03-09 06:00:00.000 2015-03-09 08:00:00.000
172378  NULL    15,10,34,102,260    2015-03-09 06:00:00.000 2015-03-09 08:00:00.000
```

What I need is the records where locationKeyList is withing a given criteria and locationKey is also withing that list

Comment: Any thoughts on that

Comment: Might be a bit easier if you split your values in a cte first but it is hard to say exactly. Any chance you can split out that delimited list to something more normalized? Also, are you aware of what that NOLOCK hint is really doing? Are you ok with missing and/or duplicate data? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidlean/archive/2009/04/06/sql-server-nolock-hint-other-poor-ideas.aspx

Comment: No I am not OK with a duplicated data or missing data

Comment: Here are three of my favorite articles discussing what NOLOCK is really doing. Not saying not to use it but you need to understand fully what it does and what it might mean to your results. http://www.jasonstrate.com/2012/06/the-side-effect-of-nolock/ http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/tonyrogerson/archive/2006/11/10/1280.aspx http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidlean/archive/2009/04/06/sql-server-nolock-hint-other-poor-ideas.aspx

Comment: Now about your actual question...did you get what I meant about splitting preflight with a cte? What about normalizing the data permanently instead of storing it in a delimited list?

Comment: I have inherited the database that way and it is tool late to change

Comment: OK I get that. What about splitting them in a cte first? In the code you posted you have a hard coded list that you are splitting. I assume those values come from a table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't you have to cross apply like that?

```
CROSS APPLY
(
SELECT match
FROM DelimitedSplit8K('10,260,34,102,15', ',')
) as t(country)
```